# How is Jackie still alive after another intimate encounter?

Tags: comics, top-cow-universe

In Artifacts #9, Jackie Estacado (current wielder of the Darkness, cursed to die and father the next bearer of the Darkness if he ever gets intimate) sleeps with

> Sara Pezzini, wielder of the Witchblade.

When it's mentioned that he could die if they continue (which they do), he states something along the lines of "it worked out for my last time - I can make the Darkness do whatever I want."  Last time refers to when the Darkness possessed his body without his knowledge and fathered Hope, Sara Pezzini's child (which was an attempt by the Darkness to tip the scales in his battle against the Angelus).

Meanwhile, in The Darkness ongoing title, the Darkness is actively and consciously rebelling against Jackie, attempting to kill him so that another bearer can be named.

Is there any explanation given to why Jackie is able to control the Darkness and prevent his death during the events of the Artifacts mini-series?

Comment: He uses contraception.

Comment: @Kalamane I think they've actually covered that if he attempted that, the Darkness would...circumvent their success.  It's not delved into too deeply, likely for reasons of propriety.

Comment: Maybe he just has blue balls